# Chat text entry box invisible in Android Chrome Beta (67)

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web

The only issue I can see is the text entry box: there's just a blank space where the it should be. It's actually still there, though, just invisible. If I tap it, the keyboard comes up and I can type, but I can't see the text I've entered either.

[image]

I can only reproduce this in Android Chrome Beta (67.0.3396.29), and this is on a Pixel 2. Everything's fine in default Android Chrome (66.0.3359.126).

Comment: tl;dr We do not support beta browsers.

Comment: Okay, so I guess we just hope that it's fixed in Chrome before it hits stable and I re-report otherwise?

Comment: Yes, that's what you should do.